# Can I set a Thunderbird tag to be added for all new messages in a folder?

Tags: thunderbird, tags

In Thunderbird I would like every message in folder X to have tag X when the message is added. It would allow me to synchronize Thunderbird tags with GMail labels.

- I tried to create a filter but there is no such trigger like "is in
  folder X".
- I created a tag with the same name as the folder but it
  doesn't apply it when I move message to a folder.
- I couldn't find any
  extension to solve this problem.

Comment: Regrettably, "When you select to run a filter manually you can apply the filter to a specific folder. This is not possible for the automatic execution of filters." https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters . It's easy to select all messages in a folder *after* they arrive and add a tag, but not automatically, AFAIK. However, see https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/extensions/folders-and-filters/ for a list of extensions, one of which might help.